# httpsessionstate in firefox

Tags: asp.net

I have an ashx file (http handler) with my asp.net app. Now it seems like that every time I store a value in session state it does not really get stored, meaning if I click a button then check for the session it always returns null. However it is working fine in IE8. can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cookies are enabled for the site in Firefox, and that you don't have any script errors.

Comment: definitely has been enabled and no script error. if there was a script error then it would have not worked in IE either.

Comment: @User: There could be a Firefox-only script error (eg, referencing elements by ID).  What do you see in Firebug?

Comment: firebug did not yield any script error. so pretty sure there was no script error.